# How to add multiline to data attribute in angular

Tags: angular, pseudo-element, angular-dom-sanitizer

I'm using [Quill Editor](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill) inside an angular project and I need multiline placeholders. Since Quill renders the placeholders via `::before` I thought it should be straight forward to implement this, as specified in [this SA question about multiline data attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451553/css-data-attribute-new-line-character-pseudo-element-content-value).

I get the placeholders from the Backend via Json:

```
placeholder : 'Line number 1 &#xa; Line number 2'
```

When I put this as value for `placeholder` these "new line" indicators are not rendered as new line but rather as text.

```
<quill-editor [placeholder]="rtePlaceholder">
```

When I edit the page with Dev Tools and copy paste the string from the JSON into the generated `data-placeholder` attribute it renders correctly.

I thought I maybe have to bypass the domsanitizer [somehow as said in this SA question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438039/correct-way-provide-domsanitizer-to-component-with-angular-2-rc6)

```
 <quill-editor [placeholder]="getRtePlaceholder()">

 getRtePlaceholder() {
  // hardcoded string to better show it, here will then be the value from the JSON.
  this.rtePlaceholder = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('Line 1. &#xa; Line1');
  }
  return this.rtePlaceholder;
 }
```

Now I run [into this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474173/safevalue-must-use-property-binding-although-im-already-using-property-bindin), I get `SafeValue must use [property]=binding although I'm already using property binding`. (another [SA question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351434/safe-value-must-use-property-binding-after-bypass-security-with-domsanitizer), and [even another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438039/correct-way-provide-domsanitizer-to-component-with-angular-2-rc6))

But these question are mostly only about innerhtml (one is about src for iframe) but I never got any of these to work.

So my question is: Is this the correct way to get the multiline attribute for angular? And if so, how do I escape it correctly? If not, how else do I get multiline data-attribute to render in Angular?